# Create web service for notification purpose?

Tags: php, web-services, cakephp, soap, notifications

I have built an ecommerce website in CakePHP and MySQL which takes orders and stores them in db. I've been told that I need to create a web service for sending notification to desktop/via email which would alert us of any order given instantly and would also provide us with order details. Do i need to study up on web services, SOAP, GET POST etc. or can I do it with some easier method? What would be a secure and fast response way of receiving such a notification from the web application? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

A webservice would be useful the other way round. If a third-party entity wishes to access your website as a service without accessing HTML pages, yes in that case, creating a webservice on your end will be useful.

I recommend you for instance to see the RESTful webservice interface to stackoverflow/stackexchange itself to understand this concept: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs.

In your case, I can't see how webservices would be involved. If you just need to send emails from your website, it can be done directly with the PHP [mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, or using a mailer like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Desktop notifications are an entirely different matter, because you need a client software.
I haven't dug pretty far in that topic myself, but here are a few pointers:

A popular Desktop Notification software for MacOSX is [Growl](http://growl.info/) which has been unofficially ported to Windows: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/

There is a PHP API to send messages to Growl clients: http://clickontyler.com/php-growl/.

Comment: Thanks :) I just confirmed, i'm told web service has to be made to use GET POST PUT DELETE etc. to authenticate login signup of user from the server somehow, and also use it to send a message from server to our devices like android/apple phones/tablets, desktop whatever for notification of order, basically acting like an alarm. Is there any way besides web services I can use? How can REST be used to do this? Also, what frameworks for building web services would be useful for this? THANKYOU!
PS- The person kept mentioning that we'll receive data in JSON ...does that help?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You are talking about webservices as if they were an end by themselves, but what do they have to do with the alert system ? Who is supposed to call those webservices ? I'm afraid there are two completely different issues here.

Comment: I'm supposed to make the server issue a command via REST ie. using GET POST etc. to a web service which would then ping/alert us on our local devices? If we forget about webservices for a bit, is there a piece of code I can write in Cakephp which would enable me to recieve info from a user, save it on server and simultaneously send it to our local devices as an alert?

Comment: getting info from user, save it to database seems straightforwards to write in PHP, calling a webservice, you can do that using the CURL api: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php